# Swift - Cover ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

right now I am only using one `viewController` for my mainMenue. But that brings up a couple of problems and I would like to separate my `popUpView` from the `viewController`. In the picture you can see how it looks like right now. My problem right now is that I want the popUpView to be slightly transparent (as you can see in the picture) so you can still see the mainMenue in the background. Currently I am simply using the `.alpha`-attribute to let the popUpView appear and disappear. Any idea how I can achieve this with two `ViewControllers`?

[image] [image]

```
   // set the closure
   cell.tapCallback = {

    self.listNameTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.blurrImage.alpha = 0.96
        self.newListView.alpha = 1
        self.newListTextfield.alpha = 1
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


@IBAction func closeButtonTappedNewList(_ sender: Any?) {
    self.newListTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
    self.listNameTextfield.text = ""
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.blurrImage.alpha = 0
        self.newListView.alpha = 0
        self.newListTextfield.alpha = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to make your popup another viewcontroller

Comment: that is what I'm trying to do, but I want the mainMenue (1st picture) to appear in the background. And if I just put everything in another viewController I don't see the mainMenue in the background

Comment: @Chris you can have the popup in another viewController (with clear background) and then add a Visual Effect View with blur style, build your UI on top of this and present it over the parent view controller.

Comment: how can I present the popViewController on top of the parent view controller?